# Exception thrown when using Mono+Aspose.Words running on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, aspose.words

I'm using Aspose.Words to convert a doc/docx file to a pdf file on ubuntu. Mono runtime has been installed. My code is below:

```
Document doc = new Document ("/data/upfile/test.docx");
doc.Save ("/data/upfile/test.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

Somehow, when the second line of the code is executed, an error was thrown. The detail is below:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex +
>   length > this.length Parameter name: length   at
>   System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x6c95d9cf46ff5f25.x0d299f323d241756.x3b67e683e83cab62 (System.String
>   xe4115acdf4fbfccc, Int32 x961016a387451f05) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x4469479613bec4d8
>   (Aspose.Words.Node xda5bf54deb817e37) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x7be41bff00df2c71
>   (Aspose.Words.Node xda5bf54deb817e37) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x699caa1974f95d1a
>   (Aspose.Words.Node xda5bf54deb817e37) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x21e4bd206d6231f8
>   (System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7) [0x00000] in :0
>   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.xb5ef8a04e65b87e6
>   (System.String x1f25abf5fb75e795, System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.xdeb77ea37ad74c56.xbbf9a1ead81dd3a1 (System.String
>   x1f25abf5fb75e795, System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.xbbf9a1ead81dd3a1 (System.String
>   x1f25abf5fb75e795, System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.xf3a1cfbffa44728c () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.x47f176deff0d42e2 () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.x83f07df6a659e05b () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.xcde671c53995c411.xd9db07500873ae98
>   (Aspose.Words.Document x3664041d21d73fdc,
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.xdeb77ea37ad74c56 xdfde339da46db651) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.UpdatePageLayout ()
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Aspose.Words.Document.x410db0f4a89a6ef1 (Boolean x24af0daafcd8fb8c)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Aspose.Words.Document.get_xcde671c53995c411 () [0x00000] in :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.get_PageCount () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   xf989f31a236ff98c.x6c74398bceb133f8.xa2e0b7f7da663553
>   (x28925c9b27b37a46.x8556eed81191af11 x5ac1382edb7bf2c2) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.xf381a641001e6830
>   (System.IO.Stream xcf18e5243f8d5fd3, System.String xafe2f3653ee64ebc,
>   Aspose.Words.Saving.SaveOptions xc27f01f21f67608c) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.Save (System.String
>   fileName, Aspose.Words.Saving.SaveOptions saveOptions) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.Save (System.String
>   fileName, SaveFormat saveFormat) [0x00000] in :0
>   at MonoTest.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + length > this.length
>   Parameter name: length   at System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex,
>   Int32 length) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   x6c95d9cf46ff5f25.x0d299f323d241756.x3b67e683e83cab62 (System.String
>   xe4115acdf4fbfccc, Int32 x961016a387451f05) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x4469479613bec4d8
>   (Aspose.Words.Node xda5bf54deb817e37) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x7be41bff00df2c71
>   (Aspose.Words.Node xda5bf54deb817e37) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x699caa1974f95d1a
>   (Aspose.Words.Node xda5bf54deb817e37) [0x00000] in :0   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.x21e4bd206d6231f8
>   (System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7) [0x00000] in :0
>   at x4adf554d20d941a6.x50e6e6d123fa4a35.xb5ef8a04e65b87e6
>   (System.String x1f25abf5fb75e795, System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.xdeb77ea37ad74c56.xbbf9a1ead81dd3a1 (System.String
>   x1f25abf5fb75e795, System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.xbbf9a1ead81dd3a1 (System.String
>   x1f25abf5fb75e795, System.Object xa860e35844c20ac7) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.xf3a1cfbffa44728c () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.x47f176deff0d42e2 () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.x487cdc969fefe3d6.x83f07df6a659e05b () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.xcde671c53995c411.xd9db07500873ae98
>   (Aspose.Words.Document x3664041d21d73fdc,
>   x59d6a4fc5007b7a4.xdeb77ea37ad74c56 xdfde339da46db651) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.UpdatePageLayout ()
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Aspose.Words.Document.x410db0f4a89a6ef1 (Boolean x24af0daafcd8fb8c)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Aspose.Words.Document.get_xcde671c53995c411 () [0x00000] in :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.get_PageCount () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   xf989f31a236ff98c.x6c74398bceb133f8.xa2e0b7f7da663553
>   (x28925c9b27b37a46.x8556eed81191af11 x5ac1382edb7bf2c2) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.xf381a641001e6830
>   (System.IO.Stream xcf18e5243f8d5fd3, System.String xafe2f3653ee64ebc,
>   Aspose.Words.Saving.SaveOptions xc27f01f21f67608c) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.Save (System.String
>   fileName, Aspose.Words.Saving.SaveOptions saveOptions) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at Aspose.Words.Document.Save (System.String
>   fileName, SaveFormat saveFormat) [0x00000] in :0
>   at MonoTest.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often inner exceptions is a very common problem for converting words documents in PDF via Aspose.

It can be due to some reasones like:

1. 2013 MS Word office.
2. Some complex elements in word
3. Old version of Aspose.Words.dll.

Solutions:

1. Try to update Aspose.Words.dll to new version. If it's still not working - write to aspose forum, and this error will be fixed in new release.
2. Check word document itself. may be you can find something thac call this inner exception, than try to remove it and check again. If this is acceptable of course.

Comment: It turned out that the document seems to have something wrong. I used another document and no error occured. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi,Aler,one more question.My document contains a lot of unicode characters. The converted pdf file is garbled. I've tried setting the Encoding property of the LoadOptions but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Aspose have meet this problem already. It's becouse Aspose.PDF use TrueType fonts, and for Linux, MAC OS it causes a problems. It solved in this .NET update: http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/entry422683.aspx